# Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: jni/../../cocos2d

Tags: android, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am totally new to programming.
I am using windows 7 and eclipse. 
I have searched all the place and i have tried all of the recommended solution and nothing works for me. Please let me know how to change them. 
So please help me to understand what you are trying to say.
**The cocos version i am using is 3.3 (cocos2d-x-3.3)**
NDK is version r9D
Thank you.

I am not sure why CDT Build console is giving me these errors.

"
**** Build of configuration Release for project KIKILA ****

```
    python C:/Users/SM/workspace/KIKILA/build_native.py -b release all 
    Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-15 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
    Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: jni/../../cocos2d    
    Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: jni/../../cocos2d/external    
    Android NDK: WARNING: Ignoring unknown import directory: jni/../../cocos2d/cocos    
    Android NDK: C:\apps\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\cocos\cocos2d-x-3.3\external/flatbuffers/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'external/jansson' in import path    
    jni/Android.mk:41: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
    Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/SM/workspace/KIKILA/build_native.py", line 159, in <module>
    Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
        build(opts.ndk_build_paSM,opts.android_platform,opts.build_mode)
      File "C:/Users/SM/workspace/KIKILA/build_native.py", line 146, in build
        do_build(cocos_root, ndk_root, app_android_root,ndk_build_param,sdk_root,android_platform,build_mode)
      File "C:/Users/SM/workspace/KIKILA/build_native.py", line 82, in do_build
        raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
    Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ C:\Users\SM\workspace\KIKILA ] fails!
    Android NDK:         
    make.exe: Entering directory `C:/Users/SM/workspace/KIKILA'
    make.exe: Leaving directory `C:/Users/SM/workspace/KIKILA'
    The Selected NDK toolchain version was 4.8 !

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the `build_native.py` script.

The `build_native.py` hasn't been maintained for ages and it has been deprecated. So you can't rely on it to build your Android project. But Cocos guys haven't make it clear to developers.

Try use `cocos run` command instead.

You could run the following command to build and run your project.

```
cd KIKILA
cocos run -p android
```

Before running the cocos command, you might need to configure it:

```
cd COCOS2DX_ROOT(your cocos2d-x folder)
python setup.py
```

Comment: i did not do as you recommended, but i moved my cocos from C folder to D folder and it works. 
Thank you.